# Unphysical degrees of freedom for the Weyl spinor?

Tags: fermions, dirac-equation, spinors

I am attempting to solve the Weyl equation:
$$\bar\sigma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi=0$$ Where $\bar\sigma^{\mu}=(-1,\vec{\sigma})$ in my convention, and $\phi$ is a two component Weyl spinor. I consider a plane wave solution of the form $\phi_p=u_pe^{-ip\cdot x}$ for some constant spinor $u_p$. With this anzats we see that we must have $\det(\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}p_{\mu})=-p^2=0$. There are two solutions to this for a given 3-momentum $\vec p$, namely $p_{\mu\pm}=(\pm|\vec p|,\vec p)$. The Weyl equation in terms of $u_{p\pm}$ is then:
$$\bar\sigma^{\mu}p_{\mu\pm}u_{p\pm}=0$$

The solution for $u_{p\pm}$ is simply $u_{p\pm}=\sigma^{\mu}p_{\mu\pm}v$ for some arbitrary 2-component spinor $v$.

Now, the Weyl equation demands that the $u_{p+}$ solution has positive helicity and the $u_{p-}$ solution has negative helicity, regardless of the form of $v$, since we have that $$\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{|\vec{p}|}u_{p\pm}=\pm u_{p\pm}$$

There are two linearly independent vectors $v^T=(1\quad 0)$ and $v^T=(0\quad 1)$. What do these different $v$'s correspond to physically?

Edit: I am working with the extra sign conventions $\eta_{\mu\nu}=\textrm{diag}(-1,+1,+1,+1)$ and $p_0=E.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two different $v$'s actually give the same resulting solution!

For $v_1^T=(1\quad 0)$ we have $u_{p\pm 1}^T=(\sigma^{\mu}p_{\mu\pm}v_1)^T=(\pm|\vec p|+p_3\quad p_1+ip_2)$.

And for $v_2^T=(0\quad 1)$ we have $u_{p\pm 2}^T=(\sigma^{\mu}p_{\mu\pm}v_2)^T=(p_1-ip_2\quad \pm|\vec p|-p_3)$.

These are proportional to each other, with proportionality constant $a=(\pm|\vec p|+p_3)/(p_1-ip_2)$. So you can choose any linear combination of the two and get the same solution.

Comment: I was about to answer myself. If you have 4 vectors in total, at least 2 of them must be dependent, even without having to do a computation :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Does that argument work even though it is a system of complex equations? Perhaps since the matrix is hermitian?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a vector space and any set of more than two vectors is linearly dependent with, possibly, complex coefficients. Indeed your $a$ is complex. If you have complex vectors but allow only for real linear combinations, that's the same thing as $\mathbb{R}^4$, which has dimension four obviously.